# VIM colorscheme won't load by default

Tags: python, vim

I've searched and searched but I can't figure this out.

I have a colorscheme called `python.vim` and I have placed it in my `/colors` directory.

I can use it by typing the `:colorscheme python` command.

BUT

My `.vimrc` file contains `syntax on` and `colorscheme python`, which is supposed to load the color scheme by default, but it doesn't.

Comment: Can you post your vimrc? It sounds like you are overriding the color scheme when you load. (Check for extraneous colorscheme commands)

Comment: `syntax on
set t_Co=256
colorscheme python
set nu
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set autoindent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like it might a syntax file (colors for the keywords, types, etc.) for python. If it is indeed the python.vim syntax file I think it is, it will look like this in the top of the file:

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language:     Python
" Maintainer:   Dmitry Vasiliev <dima at hlabs dot org>
" URL:          https://github.com/hdima/python-syntax
" Last Change:  2013-11-18
" Filenames:    *.py
" Version:      3.3.6
```

If it is a syntax file, you should place it in ~/.vim/syntax and it will be loaded automatically when you open a python file for editing.